# How can I read a value on a picture using php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image

How can i read the image red color value using PHP,Is this possible in PHP ? Actually i needs its measurements like the one in red

[image: Sample Image]

Answer (score 2):

You'll need an [OCR (Optical Character Recognition)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) package for PHP. [Tesseract OCR for PHP](https://github.com/thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php#tesseractocr-for-php) is a popular one.

Comment: i will give it a try